# I have been trying for generating QRcode image from json data using java, unable to encode value in Qrcode image

Tags: java, json, image, bitmap, barcode

- Unable to read data of type JSON line by line.
- Unable to encode value from JSON object to an image using following
  method.

```java
public static void generate_qr(String name, String data) {
    try {
        String filePath = "W:\\FileDemo\\"+name+".png";
        String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
        Map < EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel > hintMap = new HashMap <  > ();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
        BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
            new String(/*qrObj.getString("projectkey")*/data.toString().getBytes(charset), charset),
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200, hintMap);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
            .lastIndexOf(',') + 1), new File(filePath));
        System.out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");
    } catch (WriterException | IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Unable to encode value from JSON object to an image using following method"_. What does that mean exactly? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: got the output. but still unable to read the file line wise, can you help in writing loop for reading the data? I can post the entire code